# Server not starting when using Capybara and Selenium Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, testunit

I'm not 100% sure what is happening but I seem to have configured Capybara how the README suggests using selenium as the default_driver in Test::Unit. My test_helper looks like this

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  fixtures :all
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:7001'
  Capybara.run_server = true
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
end
```

The selenium driver manages to open Firefox but it loads a blank page. What am I missing, am I supposed to start the server manually because that seems daft?

I've used Capybara before albeit a long time ago and I'm sure it just worked but that was using RSpec.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A massive derp moment for me there, I forgot to `require 'capybara/rails'` into my test_helper.rb file.